# How to limit backlight LED current in 16x2 LCD

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I'm getting the error "**Current through backlight led is 23.7 kA, while maximum is 20.0 mA**". What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.print("Arduino");
  delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The two pins on the LCD which are marked "LED" are directly connected to the backlight LED. If you drive an LED over its forward voltage the current is rising exponential in relation to the voltage. Thus every LED needs a current limiting circuit, like a simple resistor in series. Otherwise the current through the LED will be so high, that it gets fried.

So to solve the problem you should place a resistor in series with the backlight LED (so for example between Vcc and the positive LED pin). The needed resistor value depends on the LED. The error message states 20mA max (just like a digital output pin on an Arduino), thus a value above R = U/I = 5V/20mA = 250 Ohm will be enough to hold the current below the maximum. To have a safety margin I would start with like 300 Ohm (depending on whats available).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried putting a 300 Ohm resistor on VCC but it didn't work. So I added it on LED Anode. It works perfectly now.

Comment: I meant on the connection between Vcc and the LED. But I think you have it now

Comment: While of course, this is going to fry the display. But if the current was really 23.7kA, that would be the smallest of the problems...

Comment: In ancient Egypt kA has an interesting and almost relevant meaning. Interesting to look up!

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit the current going to the backlight LED by putting a resistor in series with the LED.

Currently you have the LED wired to 5V and Ground with nothing to limit the current. This will result in the LED failing from over-current.

You will want to install a 330 ohm resistor in series with the LED, like illustrated in the image below. (Note the data lines are not shown to make the circuit simpler.)

[image: 16x2 LCD with current limiting resistor]